# Curried function in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, currying

I'm writing a simple typescript program that takes two arguments, x and y and passing these arguments to Math.pow(x,y).

Because i want to write a curried function that uses Math.pow(), i tried:

```
function power(x:number,y:number):number {
   return Math.pow(x,y);
}
```

But some people wrote it as:

```
function mathPow(x : number) : number => (number=>number) {

    (y : number) => Math.pow(x,y)
}
```

I was wondering if my attempt which is the first one above is considered curried as that was the simplest i could think off. Or is the second one the overall better curried version?

--Update

```
function pow(x:number):number {
  return function(y:number) {
    return Math.pow(x,y);
  }
}
```

Comment: The first one is not curried as you need to still pass all arguments when you call it. The thing with currying is that you *return* a function (that takes fewer arguments).

Comment: @trincot thanks. I have reattempted the second time in the currying syntax in the updated post. Could you look into it and inform me if i did it correctly now?

Comment: Your second attempt is the same as the "some people" one, but with `function` keyword instead of arrow function (expression) syntax. You should however change the return type of the outer function. It is not `number`, but a function. NB: a StackOverflow question is not supposed to be a clipboard being updated with new attempts during a discussion. Please fix your question to something stable.

Comment: @trincot Thank you! Will keep that in mind. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can transform any function with two arguments into its "curry version" using this custom curry function:

```
 function curry<T1, T2, T3>(fn: (a: T1, b: T2) => T3) {
      return (a: T1) => (b: T2) => fn(a, b);
 }
```

Then you can call it in that way:

```
    const curriedPower = curry(power);
    const fistArgPowerCall= curriedPower(5);
    const powerCallResult = fistArgPowerCall(5);
```

You can also extend it to handle 3 arguments:

```
function curry<T1, T2, T3, T4>(fn: (a: T1, b: T3, c: T2) => T4) {
     return (b: T3) => (c: T2) => (a: T1) => fn(a, b, c);
}
```

and so on and so forth...